# ImportError for entry_points in setup.py

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I get an `ImportError: No module named 'test.nested'` when I try to call a console script entry point defined in my `setup.py`.

- Project structure:

  ```
  test
  ├── setup.py
  └── test
      ├── __init__.py
      └── nested
          ├── __init__.py
          └── testme.py
  ```
- `setup.py`:

  ```
  from setuptools import setup, find_packages

  setup(name='test',
        version='0.1',
        packages=find_packages(),
        entry_points = {
          'console_scripts': [
              'testme=test.nested.testme:main'
              ]
          },
        zip_safe=False)
  ```
- `testme.py`:

  ```
  def main():
      print('It works!')

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
  ```

However, I get this error:

```
> pip install .
Processing my_folders/test
Installing collected packages: test
  Running setup.py install for test ... done
Successfully installed test-0.1

> testme

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "venv35/bin/testme", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('test==0.1', 'console_scripts', 'testme')()
  File "venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 560, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2648, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2302, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2308, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'test.nested'
```

What can the problem be here?

Note: in `python` shell this code works:

```
>>> import test.nested.testme
>>> test.nested.testme.main()
It works!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently I was using a bad name for my package. In fact, renaming `test` to `my_test` solved the issue.

I hope this can be useful to someone else.

Comment: This isn't an answer: `my_test` appears nowhere above!

Comment: @Colin This was from 5 years ago, but I believe the answer is valid. To fix the issue I had to rename the `test` folder to something else. I renamed it to `my_test` and it worked. Please re-upvote the answer, as it is the correct answer.

Comment: if you edit your answer to explain why it is the correct method, and how it works, then it could be helpful!